# Floating li components and keeping the ul border

Tags: html, css

The following code is what I use to style and display a navigation bar at the top of my page. However, there are lines in-between the different `li` elements.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-nav.fixed {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 50%;
  /* or right 50% */
  text-align: left;
}
.top-nav.fixed ul {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: blue;
}
.top-nav.fixed li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
.top-nav.fixed a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.top-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.top-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top-nav fixed" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In order to fix this, I changed the code to the following.

```
.top-nav.fixed li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
```

This brought around a new problem. The `ul` border no longer went around the `li` elements. My question; how do you get the `ul` border to go around all the `li` elements as it did before they were floated?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-nav.fixed {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 50%;
  /* or right 50% */
  text-align: left;
}
.top-nav.fixed ul {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: blue;
}
.top-nav.fixed li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
.top-nav.fixed a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.top-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.top-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top-nav fixed" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ - this might be what you are looking for

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+containing+floats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden` for the parent.

In your case,

```
.top-nav.fixed ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

this should help.

Also, remove `inline-block`, it's no longer useful in your code when you use float.

Comment: always a pleasure :)